How to add event liteners in Django?
I have the following code in html with a js script, but i want to add it to my django forms but i don't know how or where to start. What it does is that it automatically multiplies two numbers as the user types and shows the predict in a different part of the table.
    {% extends "blog/base.html" %} {% block content %}
<h1>About Page</h1>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Table</h2>
  <form>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Value</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="usr"></label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="num1" />
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div id="total"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="tt"></label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="num2" />
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div id="total 2"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>30</td>
          <td><div class="form-group">
              <label for="ttt"></label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="num3" />
            </div></td>
          <td><div id="total 3"></div></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
<script>
  function multiply(a, b, outputId) {
    var total = a * b;
    document.getElementById(outputId).innerHTML = total;
  }

  const num1 = document.getElementById('num1');
  const num2 = document.getElementById('num2');
  const num3 = document.getElementById('num3');

  num1.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
    console.log(event);
    multiply(10, Number(event.target.value), 'total');
  });

  num2.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
    multiply(20, Number(event.target.value), 'total 2');
  });

  num3.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
    multiply(30, Number(event.target.value), 'total 3');
  });
</script>

{% endblock content %}

I know that this must be done in mt views.py function but i dont know how or where to start.

It looks like your code already does this, and you don't need forms to do it.  What do want to accomplish by incorporating this into a Django form?  The purpose of a form in Django (and I think in general, but I'm no expert) is to submit information to a server.  Perhaps to save that information to a database, or to do something with that data, and return the result.  Secondly, I don't see any jQuery in your code, so not sure why you tagged your question with it.

My code does, but that is not a django form. Django automatically creates your forms for your templates. That code right there isnt sent to my views for processing and validation. That's why i was wondering if i coul do itin my views.
